# how to accelerate Flex Mobile and improve its performance

Tags: android, performance, hardware-acceleration, flex-mobile

I have a very simple app which runs great on the PC, but runs 'acceptably' –not by much though- on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, SM-T210). It’s a very simple app so I thought that it would have ran great from day one, but it didn’t. I’ve seen some really resourceful applications –mine cannot even compare to them- running very fast and smoothly on a tablet.  So I’ve been wondering how to accomplish that.

I’ve heard that you can accelerate your flex application using Stage3D, Starling or Feathers. I think with most frameworks I would have to rewrite part of my app because I would have to use the framework’s components to make the app run faster. I don’t know if I’m correct by this though. Is this correct?

Is there a way to accelerate my Flex Mobile app using one of those frameworks without having to rewrite a substantial part of my code? If so, can you tell me how?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Sebastián

**NEEDED FOR SOLUTION**

Every tip that Rod stated is very important. It will improve the performance of a well-constructed application and make it run smoothly. The problem with those tips is that they are the smaller “half” of the iceberg and not the bigger “half”.

My application was transitioning very slowly from one View to another and this was due to the fact that I wasn’t “respecting” the Flex’s component Lifecycle. What I mean by this is that I was performing operations of configuration of the components after they were added to the DisplayList of the View and were validated. Also, I was adding children to the view programmatically after the method INITIALIZED event was fired. This made the View take more time to recalculate its children’s properties and add some more components to its DisplayList even after that part of the its lifecycle was supposed to be done. This made it take more time to render to its final state, hence, interrupting the transition from View to View. What I needed to do was to configure the components before they were added to the DisplayList and add more components to the View before createChildren() method was done.

The best and first advice, at least from my experience, to reach a “normal” performance is to abide by the guidelines of the lifecycle. Respect the construction, configuration, attachment and initialization parts of the process and you’ll be fine. If you don’t do this, all of the advices mentioned by Rod won’t be useful to get your application to perform smoothly.

It is true that only by abiding by the lifecycle you won’t be able to get your app to the best performance. For that, you’ll definitely need the advice mentioned before, but these tips are, what I call, the second part of the iceberg. First things first, code following the guidelines of the components’ lifecycle; second, follow all of Rod’s tips. With these two you’ll have a fast-as-lightening running app.

Comment: You are correct about those frameworks requiring a complete re-write, well of your UI at least. For future AS3 mobile projects you should investigate your needs prior to implementation and device which framework to go with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Flex-Mobile app, I haven't tried using any frameworks. In order to optimize my application, I am doing the following tips:

- write item renderers on AS

  - subclass `LabelItemRenderer` or `IconItemRenderer`
  - avoid complex bindings
  - set autoDrawbackground to off
- Use `BitmapImage` over Spark Image

  - use PNGs over JPEG or GIF. it takes less image decoding and rendering time
- Text - Use StyleableTextfield (can be use only in AS)
- write skins in AS (extend `MobileSkin`)
- write custom component in AS3 not in MXML
- setElementSize is cheaper than setting width and height
- `setElementPosition` is cheaper than setting x and y properties
- use light-weight components (i.e. Label)
- use cacheAsBitmap property

  - components that are not changing frequently but are redrawn often
  - can be cached as Bitmap to optimize rendering time
- don't use `BorderContainer`, use `Group + Rect`
- reduce number of nested Groups
- use `Scroller.viewport` instead of `Scroller.verticalScrollbar`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Lists in your app? You could rewrite [ItemRenderers](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-mobile-performance-checklist.html) etc.

Comment: Hello Alexander:

I only use TileGroup on two occasions and they are populated with simple buttons. I don't think this can be the source of the speed issue. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Every tip that Rod stated is very important. It will improve the performance of a well-constructed application and make it run smoothly. The problem with those tips is that they are the smaller “half” of the iceberg and not the bigger “half”.

My application was transitioning very slowly from one View to another and this was due to the fact that I wasn’t “respecting” the Flex’s component Lifecycle. What I mean by this is that I was performing operations of configuration of the components after they were added to the DisplayList of the View and were validated. Also, I was adding children to the view programmatically after the method INITIALIZED event was fired. This made the View take more time to recalculate its children’s properties and add some more components to its DisplayList even after that part of the its lifecycle was supposed to be done. This made it take more time to render to its final state, hence, interrupting the transition from View to View. What I needed to do was to configure the components before they were added to the DisplayList and add more components to the View before createChildren() method was done.

The best and first advice, at least from my experience, to reach a “normal” performance is to abide by the guidelines of the lifecycle. Respect the construction, configuration, attachment and initialization parts of the process and you’ll be fine. If you don’t do this, all of the advices mentioned by Rod won’t be useful to get your application to perform smoothly.

It is true that only by abiding by the lifecycle you won’t be able to get your app to the best performance. For that, you’ll definitely need the advice mentioned before, but these tips are, what I call, the second part of the iceberg. First things first, code following the guidelines of the components’ lifecycle; second, follow all of Rod’s tips. With these two you’ll have a fast-as-lightening running app.